# Json MergeHandling.Replace not working as expected

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, merge

I have the same dictionary in two different JObjects. When I merge the two objects, I want the older dictionary values to be replaced by the new values. As an exmple :

one.txt

```
{
    "File" : "one.txt",
    "AnotherProp": "AnotherValue",
    "Dict" : {
        "Bob" : {
            "Surname" : "Smith"
        },
        "Sam" : {
            "Surname" : "Adams"
        }
    }
}
```

two.txt

```
{
   "File" : "two.txt",
    "SomeProp": "SomeValue"
    "Dict" : {
        "Mary" : {
            "Surname" : "Smith"
        },
        "Jane" : {
            "Surname" : "Adams"
        }
    }
}
```

My expected outcome :

```
{
      "File": "two.txt",
      "AnotherProp": "AnotherValue",
      "Dict": {
          "Mary": {
              "Surname": "Smith"
          },
          "Jane": {
              "Surname": "Adams"
          }
      },
      "SomeProp": "SomeValue"
}
```

By the sound of it, MergeArrayHandling.Replace should do this magic from me. However, that is not what I find.
Here is my code that I use :

```
var jsonOne = File.ReadAllText("one.txt");
var jsonTwo = File.ReadAllText("two.txt");

var lObjOne = JObject.Parse(jsonOne);
var lObjTwo = JObject.Parse(jsonTwo);

lObjTwo.Merge(lObjOne, new JsonMergeSettings
{
     MergeArrayHandling = MergeArrayHandling.Replace,
     PropertyNameComparison = StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase
 });

 Console.WriteLine(lObjTwo.ToString(Formatting.Indented));
 Console.ReadKey();
```

And then my outcome :

```
{
  "File": "one.txt",
  "AnotherProp": "AnotherValue",
  "Dict": {
    "Mary": {
      "Surname": "Smith"
    },
    "Jane": {
      "Surname": "Adams"
    },
    "Bob": {
      "Surname": "Smith"
    },
    "Sam": {
      "Surname": "Adams"
    }
  },
  "SomeProp": "SomeValue"
}
```

As you can see, the dictionary didn't replace, and the "File" property is still the original file, not the new value.

Clearly, I'm missing something here. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `MergeArrayHandling` should work on array. Dictionary is an object.

Comment: @DragandDrop, after some experimentation, I found exactly that. Works like a charm with arrays, not with dicts. Do you perhaps have another suggestion on how to do this?

Comment: Nope. Reading the doc it seems that there is no builtin way to do that using merge setting. You can try The unit test from github you case migt be cover there https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json.Tests/Linq/MergeTests.cs